# Set category id in product list block

Tags: magento, block

I have the following block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="rotation_products" as="rotation_products" template="catalog/product/rotate.phtml">
   <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>53</category_id></action>
</block>
```

In magento 1.4 it was working.

When I've upgraded to 1.9.1 it started to show the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:203:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

After I researched I found that $this->getCategoryId() in List.php block class returns empty. So looks like the following:

```
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>53</category_id></action>
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 0):

Try replace action to

`<action method="setData"><name>category_id</name><value>53</value></action>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="rotation_products" as="rotation_products" category_id ="53" template="catalog/product/rotate.phtml">
```